# How to use White to test OpenFileDialog on Silverlight 4.0 application?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, openfiledialog, white-framework

I'm trying to test an `OpenFileDialog` that is created when the user clicks on a button in my Silverlight 4.0 application.  According to the FAQ, the correct way of finding modal dialogs is this:

```
Window mainWindow = application.GetWindow("main");
List<Window> modalWindows = mainWindow.ModalWindows(); //list of all the modal windows belong to the window.
Window childWindow = mainWindow.ModalWindow("child"); //modal window with title "child"
childWindow.IsModal; //returns true
```

However, I'm testing a Silverlight application, using the `White.WebBrowser.Silverlight.SilverlightDocument` class, which doesn't appear to have a `ModalWindows()` collection on it.

Could someone please give me a hint as to what I'm doing wrong, & how I should be testing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[viveksingh](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/viveksingh) has [provided the answer](http://white.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=204953) over on the White discussion forum:

> have you tried finding the ModalWindow
>   from InternetExplorerWindow object?